# Embedding youtube videos on safari not working

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, safari, embedding

I'v been trying to display embedded youtube videos but it does not show up on safari but it works on all other browsers. (sometimes it works)

Firstly I tried to change the link url to http from https. After this it started showing up sometimes but now always.

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/OYbXaqQ3uuo?ecver=1" width="100%" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Check through the following steps -

1. Install Adobe Flash Player.

   http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

   Restart
2. Are Plug-ins Enabled?

   Enable Plug-ins:
   `Safari > Preferences > Security`

   Web Content: Click in the box for "Enable Plug-ins".
3. Check  whether you are currently  in  YouTube HTML 5 trial.

   http://www.youtube.com/html5

   At the bottom  left of the page  uncheck the box for- `"You are currently in the HTML5 trial".`
4. Reset Safari.

   - Click Safari in the menu bar.
   - From the drop down select "Reset Safari".
   - Uncheck the boxes next to all items.
   - Check the box next to "Remove all website data".
   - Click "Reset".

I had the same problem btw. If this doesn't work, try deleting the PDF related plugins and follow the same steps. It should work out then!